# Is there a way to generate a PE from a web assembly module?

Tags: ida, x86, pe

I am in the process of analysing a large web assembly. I have the compiled .wasm file and using the tools available I can convert this to a .wat text representation. Currently, I am doing the following to convert each function within the wasm into its jit-ed assembly code:

```
// wasm is the binary; loaded from file
var module = new WebAssembly.Module(wasm);
var code = wasmExtractCode(module);
var regions = code.segments.filter(s => s.kind === 0);
regions.map(function(seg) {
      var segmentcode = code.code.subarray(seg.funcBodyBegin, seg.funcBodyEnd);
      // segmentcode contains the assembly code
});
```

Is there a way of using the code extracted in this way? Ideally, I'd like to generate a PE or some type of file I can drop in Ida and explore and analyse. I understand though that the format of wasm and PE files are fundamentally different and so this is a pretty big ask. If I dump the code from each function into a file and align each function properly, I can open the file in Ida and manually mark the function start and end, and I am then able to analyse it nicely. Doing this for over 27000 functions is a bit of an ask, though...

Any ideas?
TIA